# DataContext vs implementation of DbContext?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to Delete and Create my database using a connection string from code like this:

```
// NOT WORKING: private ProjectDataSource _dataSource;
private DataContext _dataSource;

public void Initialize ()
{
// NOT WORKING: _dataSource = new ProjectDataSource(connectionString);
_dataSource = new DataContext(connectionString); 
_datasource.DeleteDatabase();
_datasource.CreateDatabase();
}
```

If I use a `DataContext` object it works, however if I use my implementation of `DbContext`, it doesn't.  I get "cannot resolve symbol DeleteDatabase" with ProjectDataSource.  This is `ProjectDataSource`:

```
public class ProjectDataSource : DbContext, IProjectDataSource
    {

        public ProjectDataSource() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        public ProjectDataSource(string connectionString) : base("connectionString")
            {

            }

        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }


        void IProjectDataSource.Save()
        {
            SaveChanges();
        }

        IQueryable<Item> IProjectDataSource.Items
        {
            get { return Items; }
        }

    }
```

What's the best way to get this working?

Comment: Updated my post with details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a constructor taking the connection string as parameter:

```
public ProjectDataSource(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
{
}
```

and then:

```
public void Initialize ()
{
    _dataSource = new ProjectDataSource(connectionString);
    _datasource.Database.Delete();
    _datasource.Database.Create();
}
```

Comment: Just tried this but DeleteDatabase and CreateDatabase aren't recognized... but _dataSource.Database.Delete is.  Thoughts?

Comment: The Database property on the DbContext exposes the following methods: `Create`, `CreateIfNotExists` and `Exists`. There are no such methods as DbContext.DeleteDatabase or DbContext.CreateDatabase so it is perfectly normal that they are not recognized.